# Qt Bluetooth AVRCP Implementation

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluez, avrcp, hfp

I'm working on Qt project and I successfully implemented Bluetooth connection using "HandsfreeAudioGateway" so I can stream audio.

As a next step I would like to implement AVRCP to control the audio player over Bluetooth.

Looks like Qt doesn't support AVRCP yet. On the other hand BlueZ has mediaAPI which I don't know how to use it in Qt.

If you can show me a way or an example to figure it out, would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [bluez-qt](https://github.com/KDE/bluez-qt) which is a Qt wrapper for Bluez 5 DBus API.

[BluezQt::MediaPlayer](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/bluez-qt/html/classBluezQt_1_1MediaPlayer.html) represents a media player interface and might be a way forward for you.